# Can site's SERP ranks be lowered by Google because of bad/toxic backlinks?

Tags: google-search, backlinks, search-results, google-ranking, penalty

The site is not under Google's manual penalty it has no other warnings in GWT about something wrong going on, it is not out of the Google index.
But the ranking positions on SERPs are lower than before.

Do I need to invest in backlink analysis to detect the bad ones and then disavow them?

UPDATE: (to why my question is different than the other topic) I don't need to diagnose other things, as I already took the course of making changes, I clearly asked a specific question about bad backlinks and would like to get an answer to it.

Comment: When you say lower than before, could you specify when the site was created, for what time was it ranking high, and since when it has a reduced ranking?

Comment: @bugbuster my site's SE traffic started rising from 12/10/13 and dropping from 2/11/14, arond 2.5 weeks ago. Site is 11y old. I don't have ads above the fold.